# Why does not my mp3 file play using audio tag from javascript in internet explorer 10?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, html5-audio

I am trying to play mp3 file using html5 audio tag. I try to start sound from javascript using play() method. My issue is very strange: mp3 file works fine in all browsers on several machines that i tested on (windows 7 and windwos 10 operating systems). But on one particular computer it does not play in internet explorer 10. The operating system on this computer is windows 7.

I am very confused: what could be cause of this issue? I tried to google my problem but i could not find anything useful about it.

i am posting my audio tag: `<audio id="bellPlay" src="images/bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="auto"></audio>` my sound file is located in `image` directory on the server.

(If i can provide you with some additional information, please let me know)

Comment: Can you post your code for the audio tag?

Comment: @DanielGale thanks for your attention. i have edited my question

Comment: does IE10 work if you add controls? <audio controls ...